# error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

how can say me what i have to change i gived an error when i add this part in my views django

```
 new = output_df.groupby([output_df['Date and Time'].dt.date, 'PCR POS/Neg']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
        new.sort_values(by=['Date and Time'], ascending=True)
        new['Total per date'] = output_df.groupby([output_df['Date and Time'].dt.date])['PCR POS/Neg'].count()
        new.loc['Total', :] = new.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Because you can only use the `dt` accessor with datetimelike values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like "Date and Time" is not a column with a datetime format. You could try to transform that column with this before that line:

```
output_df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(output_df['Date and Time'])
```